# Comparar date time com uma timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Em asp mvc 4, estou a fazer uma `query` onde vou buscar os dados onde as horas são inferiores ou iguais que as introduzidas pelo utilizador. Ou seja, tenho uma `dateTime` e verifico com a variável introduzida pelo utilizador (uma `TimeSpan`) se é inferior ou não.

Por exemplo:

- Na BD tenho os dados:

  ```
  12-03-2014 12:00:00
  12-03-2014 09:30:00
  12-03-2014 18:00:00`
  ```

O utilizador insere `10:00` e o resultado será apenas:

`12-03-2014 09:30:00`

Agora não sei como fazer esta comparação. Já experimentei usar o `TimeOfDay` mas sem sucesso.

Código:

```
TimeSpan horaFim = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00); //Simular variavel introduzida
var plan = db.Planeamento.Where(p => p.DataFimAssitencia.Value.TimeOfDay <= horaFim ).toList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um time-span é um intervalo de tempo, e portanto para ser transformado em uma data absoluta precisa de uma base de cálculo. É possível usar a data atual como base de cálculo assim:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00); //Simular variavel introduzida
DateTime tempoFim = DateTime.Now - ts;
var plan = db.Planeamento.Where(p => p.DataFimAssitencia <= tempoFim ).ToList();
```

**EDIT:** 
Acho que entendi o que você quer, o problema é comparar somente a parte da hora no dia.

Assumindo que esteja usando o Entity Framework, Faça sua query assim:

```
var plan = db.Planeamento.Where(
    p => EntityFunctions.CreateTime(
           p.DataFimAssitencia.Value.Hour,
           p.DataFimAssitencia.Value.Minute,
           p.DataFimAssitencia.Value.Second)
         <= horaFim
     ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique o CAST da variável `p.DataFimAssitencia.Value`, pois você deve estar recebendo um Date e perdendo o Time. Um teste simples com os valores que você passou mostra que a saída está de acordo com o esperado.

```
  TimeSpan horaFim = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00);
  var dates = new List<DateTime>
  {
      new DateTime(2014,3,12,12,00,00),
      new DateTime(2014,3,12,09,30,00),
      new DateTime(2014,3,12,18,00,00)
  };
  var plan = dates.Where(date => date.TimeOfDay <= horaFim).ToList();
```